# Creating a hidden HTML page running in the background when a link is opened

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a hidden HTML page that runs in the background when a link is opened. This is for affiliate marketing. I need to make sure that when they make a purchase or sign up for a site they are actually doing it.

The only way I can think to do it is either with an extension or if they click the link to go to the affiliate site they will open a page that will create another page in the background that monitors that tab that is created just to make sure that the user is completing the offer. This is similar to the method of creating a Google Chrome app because it does the same thing. It has a hidden page running in the background monitoring things in the web browser and sends back information.

I thought to do it with an iframe as well but that is blocked easily I think.

I want to know what would be the best option or if either is possible at all.

Comment: Extensions work differently so you can monitor the tab using a *content script* and a *background script*. Start with [extensions overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: but, it is similar to the idea of an extension which is why I called it a google chrome app. Google chrome apps are created like extensions however they have additional properties and they do have an html page that does run in the background with scripts that run from that page. This is from my limited knowledge of this topic.

Comment: As you'll see in the overview, the extensions are quite different.

Comment: And as I have said that is why I called it an app. An app uses an html page. if you would like I could post some tutorials so you can see what is involved.

Comment: My point was that with an extension you can use different mechanisms which I believe are better suited for the task.

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to set up server-side verifications. So as soon as the user completes a task, a message can be sent to let's say an SQL server where it stores all the data of the complete/incomplete tasks.

I suggest you look into the server side option as hidden pop-ups can be misused for other illegitimate uses. And It's usually not a good practice to create a pop-up that's hidden to the user.

Comment: I understand that it is not good to do that but it really is my only option. Many of the sties that I will be having referral codes for do not have APIs and even if they do I would then have to create a special page for each one and that would be time consuming. I feel that if done right I will be able to make the information secure enough so that the info could not be used for nefarious purposes.

Comment: Mainly I was looking to take pictures of the pages on click and use those to make sure that the offer was complete so I can actually give the user money. I would not be selling their information as all of the information they have on those site I would probably have already since they will have to sign up to my site to complete the offers for cash.

Comment: Unless you can think of another way to get the information taking pictures of the pages seems to be my only option when there is no API and so there will be limited work involved. Also, all of the methods we use to conduct our tracking will be discussed in our terms of service and it will be known that in those terms of service that we will not be selling any of the info we have collected.